# Why Can't I Edit Tag Wikis on Meta PMSE?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am reporting this as a possible bug.  I find that when I click `Create Tag Wiki` to create an entry for a tag on PMSE Meta, the page reloads back to the same page:

https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-topic/info

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new tag wikis. Click the button below to get started.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 4000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

Note that this works fine on the main PMSE site.

Answer (score 1):

Meta tag wikis aren't currently editable, for now -- we generally push those out from meta.so periodically, and we don't want any local changes to get overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll keep my eye out for this change once it's finally released.